# Django дети-родители

Tags: django, дерево

Требуется создать несколько моделей, находящихся в отношениях "дети-родители". Сначала создаются родители с пустым списком детей, потом - какой-нибудь ребёнок (соответственно, тоже с пустым списком детей), он при создании принимает в аргументы уже существующего родителя (тот может быть только один), и при этом (1) у его родителя в списке детей появляется он. Хорошая ли вообще это идея и как это лучше всего реализовать?

Придумалось что-то такое, но не уверен, что это хорошо, это не работает, и не знаю, как хорошо сделать (1)

```
from django.db import models


class MainMainParent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    children = models.ManyToManyField(MainParent, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class MainParent(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(MainMainParent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    children = models.ManyToManyField(NotParentAtAll, null=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class NotParentAtAll(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(MainParent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="{}/{}/".format(parent.parent,
                                                                           parent))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: children — абсолютно лишний, его можно запихнуть в related_name в ForeignKey

Comment: Понятно. Тогда необходимость в этом вопросе отпадает.